# Get Results in Unity c# from Realm ( mongodb ) for game level data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, realm

So I am a php develeoper learning unity game development. So all this is quite new to me and I am sure this question has been asked before but I just cant understand what do do..

I Have the following realm instantce set up to keep track of players level data called level stats. Its all working fine but I need to know how to get a list of all rows in the leveldata and then loop through them.

Here is my realm instance :

```
using Realms;

public class LevelStats : RealmObject
{

[PrimaryKey]
public string Level { get; set; }

public RealmInteger<int> Score { get; set; }

public LevelStats() { }

public LevelStats(string Level, int Score)
    {
    this.Level = Level;
    this.Score = Score;
    }

}
```

I then add some sample level data for testing when the app loads :

```
public class LevelScore : MonoBehaviour
{

private Realm _realm;
private LevelStats _levelStats;




void Start()
    {
    _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
    
    _realm.Write(() => {
        _levelStats = _realm.Add(new LevelStats("1", 100));
        _levelStats = _realm.Add(new LevelStats("2", 2000));
        _levelStats = _realm.Add(new LevelStats("3", 1500));
        _levelStats = _realm.Add(new LevelStats("4", 5000));
    });

    if (_levelStats is null) // if null create blank table
        {
        Debug.Log("created row");
        _realm.Write(() => {
            _levelStats = _realm.Add(new LevelStats("1", 0));
        });
        }
    Debug.Log("created row");
    }
}
```

Then on my level screen I call the following c# script to display all the Level Data stored in the instance of realm

```
    // Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    _realm = Realm.GetInstance();

    var theLevelData = _realm.All<LevelStats>();

    ///// I want to code a loop here for all the rows
    /// foreach() or while() loop or something like that but cant figure it out 

    Debug.Log("Level: " + level + "Score:  " + Score);



   

   // Debug.Log(levels.Level);
   
}
```

Any pointers would be a great help !

Comment: I think what you're asking is 'how do I loop over a results object'. Results are what's returned by a Realm query here `var theLevelData = _realm.All<LevelStats>();` . A Results object behaves very much like an array and be be looped over with a standard Foreach loop (or about a dozen of other iterating styles). Try some code, update the question with your attempt and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

A regular foreach loop will do the trick:

```
var theLevelData = _realm.All<LevelStats>();

foreach (var data in theLevelData)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Level: {data.Level} - Score: {data.Score}")
}
```

If you need index-based access, you can use LINQ:

```
var thirdLevel = theLevelData.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
var levelsCount = theLevelData.Count();
```

Or you can cast the result to `IRealmCollection`, which looks more like a readonly list:

```
var levelsCollection = theLevelData.AsRealmCollection();
var thirdLevel = levelsCollection[2];
var levelsCount = levelsCollection.Count;
```

Note that there are no performance benefits of using one or the other - the `IQueryable` returned by `_realm.All<..>` is implementing most common LINQ methods (including `ElementAt` and `Count`) so those are O(1) operations and will not iterate the entire collection.